# Error when publishing sharepoint workflow 2013 : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I'm using Sharepoint designer 2013, and apprently I can't publish sharepoint workflow 2013.

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something wrong with your SSL certificate or its settings.

Please, take a look at the following articles. Probably, they help you:

[SharePoint 2010 and Cert Trust – Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2012/03/13/sharepoint-2010-and-cert-trust-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel/)

[Installing Workflow Manager failed with : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13708.workflow-manager-installation-failed-with-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel.aspx)

Or alternatively if it is not a production environment, you can just register Workflow Service to HTTP protocol and port (not HTTPS). So, your cmdlet could look as follows:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite ‘https://myhost/mysite’ -WorkflowHostUri ‘http://workflowhost:12291’ -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
```

[SOURCE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b3da6599-5455-4b5d-a893-cf7ba9055e4f/sharepoint-designer-wont-publish-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the scenario will be that a custom component that resides in SharePoint  calls WCF service over HTTPS on the same or different server.  The reason for this is that SharePoint implements its own certificate validation policy to override .NET certificate validation.

Fix is to setup a trust between SharePoint and the server requiring certificate validation.

More information, please refer to [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2013/06/13/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssltls-secure-channel/).

However, if you are using SharePoint Online, you are unable to fix this issue by yourself, you can create a service request on Office 365 Admin Center->Support.

Comment: Thank you so much for these information !!

Comment: if the information helps you, please accept it as answer.